# Creating Delegates for Caching Property Accessors

Tags: c#, properties, expression-trees

I'm creating and caching property accessor delegates using the following code:

```
    static Delegate CreateGetterDelegate<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
        return (Func<T, object>)Expression.Lambda(convert, instance).Compile();
    }
```

This is working and working well (thank you StackOverflow!), however I'd like to remove the boxing/unboxing required by returning a Func of T and object. Is there any way to change the return so that the return type is a Func of T and typeofproperty ?

I.e.

```
    static Delegate CreateGetterDelegate<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        ... some magic happening here ...

        return (Func<T, typeofproperty>)Expression.Lambda(...more magic...).Compile();
    }
```

Note - I'm using VS2013 and .NET 4.5

Comment: how is this boxing/unboxing?  You are just casting a ref type..

Comment: @TMcKeown, if `T` were an `int` it would be boxing it.

Comment: ok, gotcha.  You'd have to be able to change the `Delegate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do that is for the property's type to be known at compile time, either within this method definition, or for the caller.  If the caller of this method knows what the type of the property is, then it can specify it using a second generic argument:

```
static Func<TInstance, TResult> CreateGetterDelegate<TInstance, TResult>(
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    if (typeof(TInstance) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
    return (Func<TInstance, TResult>)Expression.Lambda(convert, instance)
        .Compile();
}
```

Of course, this is just pushing the problem back to the caller.  If even the caller isn't going to know what the type of the property is, then they have the exact same problem.

At the end of the day to avoid the boxing some code somewhere needs to know *at compile time* what the type of this property is.  If someone, somewhere, will know at compile time, then you can just keep punting on solving the problem by using generics until you get to that point where someone can just use the actual known type.  If nothing ever does know the type at compile time, then there really isn't any solution to this problem.

You could possibly, if you want to get technical, avoid boxing by making things even more dynamic than they are (using reflection to call these methods that are using reflection to do stuff) but while you may, from a technical standpoint, be able to avoid the literal `box` command, you'd be losing out way more than you'd gained.  It wouldn't be a practical solution.

Comment: +1; I believe you could also do `Expression.Lambda<TResult>` right? But I guess you'd still have to cast it to a `Func<TInstance, TResult>` huh?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Whether you supply the type of the delegate for the lambda as its generic argument or cast it after compiling it isn't really relevant.  They both do the same thing, and in about the same amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above about using reflection once again got me thinking (always a dangerous prospect) and I've come up with the following solution, basically implementing Servy's suggestion:

```
    static Delegate CreateGenericGetterDelegate<TClass>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var method = typeof(Cache).GetMethod("CreateTypedGetterDelegate"); 
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(TClass), propertyInfo.PropertyType });
        return (Delegate) generic.Invoke(new object(), new object[] { propertyInfo });
    }

    public static Delegate CreateTypedGetterDelegate<TClass, TProp>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(TClass) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        if (typeof(TProp).IsValueType)
        {
            return (Func<TClass, TProp>)Expression.Lambda(property, instance).Compile();
        }
        else
        {
            return (Func<TClass, TProp>)Expression.Lambda(Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(TProp)), instance).Compile();
        }
    }
```

This works, provides type-safe access and avoids any obvious boxing/unboxing. Since this is happening once at the beginning of my program (and only for properties being actually accessed), I'm ok with the performance hit for reflection, in return for typed delegates for property accessors.

Comment: This method doesn't serve any purpose.  The given delegate still needs to be cast to the actual delegate type in order to invoke it, which requires knowing the property's type at compile time.  Either that, or it requires using `DynamicInvoke`, which is still going to be boxing the result.  Your `CreateGenericGetterDelegate` method has added zero value over the implementation in the OP, since you still return a `Delegate`, instead of something deriving from it.

Comment: Hmm... So, basically what you're saying is that while this is *technically correct* (i.e., it works), what I'm really doing is a lot of work for no real gain because of returning a Delegate and use DynamicInvoke on the result? So, at least I learned something even if I did do the equivalent of the old exercise where everyone gets out of the car at a stoplight and runs around the car, trying to get back in before the light turns green...

Comment: And finally, some weirdness to round out the day. I did some timings over calling the original "CreateGetterDelegate" in the OP and the genericized "CreateGenericGetterDelegate" in this answer. I also did some timings on calling the returned delegates via DynamicInvoke. Over 100000 iterations, the OP method took 11602 milliseconds on average and the updated generic version took 10194 milliseconds. While these are quite pokey (over 1 ms per call!) it's interesting that the "generic" version was always just a skosh faster.

Comment: Doing the same test for the returned delegates, the delegate returned by the OP ran 100000 iterations in an average of 93 ms to an average of 92 ms for the genericized version. Again, the generic 'do a lot more' version was just a bit faster. Definitely a counterintuitive result, to say the least. Still, compared to an average of 0 ms for 100000 access directly to the property, we're still much slower going through delegates than directly to the property.

Comment: And finally, a result I did expect. The delegate in the OP can be cast to a Func of T and object and used directly, while the delegate in the second has to be called through DynamicInvoke. (This is what Servy is talking about just above - finally got through my thick head). Calling the delegate from the OP directly for 100000 iterations takes just 3 ms versus the 92 average above. So, in conclusion, is there any way to mark this answer as "interesting but not right?".

Comment: You said that your answer is technically correct.  It is not.  There is no way of using this solution and avoiding boxing.  You've called the method without boxing the result, but the method you designed to call it only exposes that method in yet another way that *will require the result to be boxed*.  It's pushing the problem one level up, not eliminating it.  As for your performance tests, the times you've described are so close together that the difference is smaller than the amount of "noise" on your machine.  Statistically they are exactly the same, yours isn't faster.

Comment: Agreed. The close times are well within the margin of error. What I found interesting was that they were close, despite the extra level of reflection. To clarify, my use of "technically correct" means that it compiles and runs. It is clearly not the best solution, despite being an interesting exercise and a learning experience. Thanks again for all your help!